# For loop, Performance

Tags: c#, .net

i have a few question regarding for loops, if you can point me to some sources or answer me here directly I would appreciate it.

The question is:

```
for(int i=0;i<List.Count();i++)
{
 //some code
}
```

is this FASTER or SLOWER comparing to this:

```
int count = list.Count();

for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
{
  //some code
}
```

and is it the same if I use `Dictionatry.Count()` or `List.Count()`. Does it always call the `Count()` function when it iterates in the for loop I'm kinda confused about this, do i gain any performance boosts?

Comment: The `Systems.Collections.Generic.List` class has a property `Count`. Use it.

Comment: The part with the most impact on performance is `//some code`

Comment: @Alex so in any way the prop is faster then the method right?

Comment: @HenkHolterman nice one :D

Comment: Seriously. It matters a whole lot if you have array-accesss in there that has to be range-checked etc. This is a question about Jitter optimization, not about C#.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Jitter optimization? please elaborate that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the `Count()` extension method, then it will be slower. If you are using the `Count` property of the `List<T>` class then there is no real performance difference.

Here is the result of a benchmark that I did (looping a list with 100 items a million times using each method):

```
Count(): 0,001558941 ms.
Count:   0,000349602 ms.
count:   0,000352088 ms.
```

Using the `Count` property or a local variable performs equally. Using the `Count()` method is about 4.5 times slower.

Eventhough the `Count()` method doesn't loop the items to count them but actually uses the `Count` property (otherwise it would be much *much* slower), it takes some time to check the type of the object to determine that there is a `Count` property to use.

Answer (score 2):

In your first case, `List.Count()` will be executed at each loop, 
so it is slower than executing it before the loop.

As said in comment by @Mr Smith, a good practice is to calculate the length of the array at the initialisation:

```
for(int i=0,len=list.Count;i<len;i++)
```

It is equivalent to:

```
int count = list.Count();
for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
```

but it is more compact.

Comment: Please explain how do you reach this conclusion

Comment: @Steve By definition that anything is slower than a local variable

Comment: True for the method invocation, so you should use a local variable for `IEnumerable<>`, but on array and lists you can just use the corresponding property (`array.Length` and `list.Count`).

Comment: Should also throw a mention of "for(int i=0,len=list.Count;i<len;i++)" pattern.

Comment: @xanatos for an array that is not necessarily true, when doing `for (var i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++) ...` the compiler would omit the index range checks.

Comment: @Alex Yep... I was looking at that in these minutes :-) http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clrcodegeneration/archive/2009/08/13/array-bounds-check-elimination-in-the-clr.aspx

Comment: @Franky For array there are special optimizations, but for `List<>`, `Count` is a standard property, so it is simply backed by a field. A field access of a reference type is slower than a local variable access, because it is an indirect access (in C it would be `(*lst).Count` instead of being simply `count`)

Comment: @xanatos Alright, but I really don't now what the time difference between those two is! :-)

Comment: @Franky To make it simple, to access the local variable count, the computer looks directly at the stack, to a (relatively) fixed position. To access lst.Count the computer has to: access directly the stack to get the `lst` reference, from that reference go around the memory and read the `_Count` field of `List<>` ("properties" have a backing field... They can't contain directly data). Two memory accesses instead of one. Note that this is ultra-micro-optimization. A single additional memory access for each cycle is like a drop in a glass. It is more theoretical than practical

Answer (score 1):

It depend on the type of `List`. The `Count` method is a LINQ Extension method and optimized for different types. If `List` is an `ICollection<T>` or an `ICollection`, it will simply return the value of the `Count`property.
I guess it is similar for `IList` and arrays.

So it is not decisive slower to use the `Count` method in some cases. But in this cases, you can use often the `Count` or `Length` property of the type.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `Count()` is a LINQ extension method, and will cause your code to run slower, you are probably wanting to use the `Count` property.

I used the following code to benchmark your question:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var runs = 1000; //Run the code this many times
    var sb = new StringBuilder(); //To test, it will add to a string builder


    //Create list
    var list = new List<int>();
    for (var i = 0; i < 50000; i++)
        list.Add(i);

    //Try Count() each iteration
    var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (var x = 0; x < runs; x++)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < list.Count(); i++)
            sb.Append(list[i]); //Just give it something to do
        sb.Clear();
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Count() each iteration, {0}ms", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

    //Try Count() once
    stopwatch.Restart();

    for (var x = 0; x < runs; x++)
    {
        var count = list.Count;
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
            sb.Append(list[i]);
        sb.Clear();
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Count() once, {0}ms", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The actual code alternated between each a few times, to make sure it wasn't biased towards a result.

**Results:**

> *50,000 integer array 1,000 times:*
>
> Count() each iteration, 6587ms
>
> Count() once, 6006ms
>
> *100,000 integer array 10,000 times:*
>
> Count() each iteration, 132854ms
>
> Count() once, 121221ms